# Defining a function that will print each factorial of y from 0 up to a specified value

Tags: python, list, function, range, factorial

I'm trying to get the function input to be similar to

`RangeFactorial(10)`

and the function produce the factorials of each number from 0 to 10

Currently I have:

```
def RangeFactorial(n)
    result = 1
    for x in range(1, n +1):
         result = result * x
    return result

for n in range(1, 10):
    print(n, RangeFactorial(n))
```

The outcome is fine, but I would the range input be like I stated above.

Additionally, I want the output to be a list and I've no idea where to start with that.

Answer (score 0):

The function you call `RangeFactorial` is just the regular factorial function:

```
def factorial(n)
    result = 1
    for x in range(1, n +1):
         result = result * x
    return result
```

`RangeFactorial` would be the function that *calls* `factorial` 10 times:

```
def range_factorial():
    for n in range(1, 10):
        print(n, factorial(n))
```

To build a list instead of printing the values, you can do, for example,

```
def range_factorial():
    result = []
    for n in range(1, 10):
        result.append(factorial(n))
    return result
```

Comment: Calling `factorial()` each time is inefficient, since `factorial(n)` is simply `factorial(n-1)*n`. So it would be better to build up the list in a single loop.